# Elasticsearch: Filter the records based on nested field with nested field containing only the filtered object

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to filter the records based on nested field and want only the matching object in that array to be shown as part of the record.
Below is the detailed explanation of my requirement.

So, I have Elasticsearch data like this:

```
[{
  "basicInfo": {
    "requestId": 123,
  },
  "managerInfo": {
    "manager": "John",
    
  },
  "groupInfo": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "name": "abc",
      "status": "Approved"
    },
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "name": "abc",
      "status": "Pending"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "basicInfo": {
    "requestId": 233,
  },
  "managerInfo": {
    "manager": "John Sr",
    
  },
  "groupInfo": [ 
    {
      "id": "id3",
      "name": "abc",
      "status": "Pending"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I want to filter the records only with groupInfo.status as Approved and basicInfo.requestId as 123, but my condition is I should only get the Approved record in the groupInfo and not the pending ones. So, the output I am expecting is:

```
{
  "took": 23,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 3.0602708,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "request",
        "_id": "123",
        "_score": 3.0602708,
        "_source": {
          "basicInfo": {
            "requestId": 123
          },
          "managerInfo": {
            "manager": "John"
          },
          "groupInfo": [
            {
              "id": "id1",
              "name": "abc",
              "status": "Approved"
            }
            // No id2 here as it is in pending state
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But instead I am able to achieve:

```
{
  "took": 23,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 3.0602708,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "request",
        "_id": "123",
        "_score": 3.0602708,
        "_source": {
          "basicInfo": {
            "requestId": 123
          },
          "managerInfo": {
            "manager": "John"
          },
          "groupInfo": [
            {
              "id": "id1",
              "name": "abc",
              "status": "Approved"
            },
            {
              "id": "id2",
              "name": "abc",
              "status": "Pending"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the query I am using:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "basicInfo.requestId": "123"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "groupInfo",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "groupInfo.status": "Approved"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, my question is first what I am expecting, is that even possible? Can we filter the result and make sure that we get only the matched array from that result?
If yes, how can we do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [Inner Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits).

> In many cases, it’s very useful to know which inner nested objects (in
> the case of nested) or children/parent documents (in the case of
> parent/child) caused certain information to be returned. The inner
> hits feature can be used for this. This feature returns per search hit
> in the search response additional nested hits that caused a search hit
> to match in a different scope.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "basicInfo.requestId": "123"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "groupInfo",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "groupInfo.status": "Approved"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits":{}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```